# Access instance variables from an activity inside a AsyncTask

Tags: android, instance, android-asynctask, instance-variables

I have an AsyncTask (in a separate file) which is invoked on an
activity. When I instantiate the AsyncTask, I send the activity as a
param. How can I access the acitivity's instance variables from the
onPostExecute method of the AsyncTask?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You must be careful when passing an Activity or `Context` to an `AsyncTask` that is not an inner (non-static) class of an Activity - this is because in this case the lifetime of the `Activity`/`Context` and the `AsyncTask` are different, and if you hold on to an `Activity`/`Context` for longer than you should you will cause memory leaks.

Rather than holding onto the Activity or activity context itself in your `AsyncTask` you should keep a  `WeakReference` to the Activity. This will ensure that the memory associated with the Activity can be reclaimed by the garbage collector (GC) when needed.

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<..., ..., ...> {
    private WeakReference<MyActivity> mParentActivity = null;

    public MyTask(MyActivity parentActivity) {
        mParentActivity = new WeakReference<MyActivity>(parentActivity);
    }

    @Override
    public ... doInBackground(... params) {
        // do some stuff

        // now we do something that requires the context
        if (mParentActivity.get() != null) {
            // the WeakReference is still valid and hasn't been reclaimed
            // by the GC
            final MyActivity parentActivity = mParentActivity.get();
            parentActivity.doSomething();
        }

        // return result
    }
}
```

When passing a `Context` always try to use the `ApplicationContext` where possible as this is the longest-lived context.

Comment: The `parentActivity.doSomething()` is called on the background thread. If the method modifies the UI you will get `CalledFromWrongThreadException`. Run such methods in the `postExecute` callback.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Programmer Bruce's answer but instead of passing the Activity as a Param through the AsyncTask itself, simply add a constructor to take the parent Activity. Example from my own code...

```
public class FileDownloader extends AsyncTask<..., ..., ...> {
    private MyActivity parentActivity = null;

    public FileDownloader(MyActivity parentActivity) {
        this.parentActivity = parentActivity;
    }
}
```

When you create it in your Activity just do this...

```
FileDownloader fdl = new FileDownloader(this);
fdl.execute(...);
```

**EDIT:** In reply to your comment, make sure mLogin is declared as `public` then use...

```
parentActivity.mLogin
```

If that doesn't work, try...

```
((MyActivity)parentActivity).mLogin
```

Comment: How can I access the instance variables after this? I can't do parentActivity.mLogin, I'm missing something...

Comment: @user177468: See the EDIT at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend from `AsyncTask<Object, x x>`, and you can then pass in any number of arbitrary parameters you like, no need to pass around reference to the whole Activity.

```
 new CustomTask().execute(param1, param2, param3);
```

Which you can reference in your doInBackground:

```
 public Void doInBackground(Object... params) {
    Integer id = (Integer) params[0];
    String name = (String) params[1];
    ....
 }
```