# Call a Fragment in Asyncktask OnPostExecute method

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences

I have a little problem, I have a AsyncTask where I get a response from the server if the user is registered or not, would that after the call, if the user accesses exist in another fragment, also by storing in a preferences user email, however I have problem when I call `getFragmentManager()`, could someone help me out? Thank you. This is my code.

`LoginTask.java`

```
public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, User> {

public LoginTask() {

}

@Override
protected User doInBackground(String... params) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setEmail(params[1]);
    user.setPassword(params[2]);

    // Set the Content-Type header
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "json"));
    HttpEntity<User> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<User>(user, requestHeaders);

    // Create a new RestTemplate instance
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    // Add the Jackson and String message converters
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

    // Make the HTTP POST request, marshaling the request to JSON, and the response to a String
    ResponseEntity<User> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(params[0], HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, User.class);

    return responseEntity.getBody();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(User user) {
    if (user.getSuccess()){
        android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new AreaRiservataFragment()).commit();
    }else{

    }
 }
}
```

I get the error: `Cannot Resolve Method 'getFragmentManager()'`.

Comment: add `@Override` before `onPostExecute(......)`

Comment: The error remains, nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

The best solution might be to make your `AsyncTask` a nested class of your activity.

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

...


  class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, User> {

    ...

    @Override
    protected User doInBackground(String... params) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(User user) {
        ...
    }
  }
}
```

If it is not possible for you, you can pass your activity as a parameter to `AsyncTask`. Have a look at the good example [Access instance variables from an activity inside a AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024658/access-instance-variables-from-an-activity-inside-a-asynctask).